# send associative array from ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, associative-array

my query gives result query_string and query_string_id i want that result to provide data for ajax and send it to php

but i dont know 
how to send associative array through ajax

pls help me to build my code

```
function querySuccessEnds(tx,results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    var deltaArray=new Array();
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        deltaArray[i]=[];
        deltaArray[i]['query']=results.rows.item(i).query_string
        deltaArray[i]['sync_query_id']=results.rows.item(i).sync_query_id
    }

    var data_to_send = JSON.stringify(deltaArray);
    console.log("data"+data_to_send);
    $.ajax({//to get online data
        type:"POST",
        url:galileoServer + "actions.php",
        data:"get=update&queries="+data_to_send,
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }); //EOC ajax

}// EOC successUpdate
```

my php file

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['queries']));


foreach($data as $a){
    echo $a->sync_query_id;
    echo $a->query;
}
```

Comment: i think you meant to use `JSON.stringify(deltaArray);`

Comment: i used it but its of no use

Comment: what exactly does the script receive? maybe there are breaking characters in the query....try using encodeURIComponent(data_to_send);

Comment: i cannot see data at this line means data_to_send hasn't stringyfy console.log("data"+data_to_send);

Comment: try without json stringify: `data:{get:'update',queries:deltaArray}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the volume of the data sent, i'd suggest either using the data directly:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:galileoServer + "actions.php",
    data:{get:'update',queries:deltaArray},
    success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

or using FormData:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("get","update");
formdata.append("queries",deltaArray)

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:galileoServer + "actions.php",
    data:formdata,
    success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

ofc this leads to a change in your php:

```
$data = $_REQUEST["queries"];
```